# Dependency @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap must be explicitly whiteliste

Tags: ng-bootstrap, angular6, angular-cli-v6

In `angular 6` project, I created angular library using `angular cli` command `ng g lierary @some/libName`. In my library, I have a component which needs `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`, so I added it by `npm i --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`.

When I try to build the library using command `ng build @some/libName --prod` it throws below error.

```
Dependency @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap must be explicitly whiteliste
```

Did anyone solved it?

Answer (score 66):

#### Update

This warning is coming from [`ng-packagr`](https://github.com/dherges/ng-packagr) ([and there's now a section of the ng-packagr docs about this](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/dependencies.md#whitelisting-the-dependencies-section)). Turns out `ng-packagr` is just telling you that it wants you to add all dependencies to an `"allowedNonPeerDependencies": []` property in `ng-package.json` (this option used to be called `"whitelistedNonPeerDependencies"`).
For example:

```
{
  "allowedNonPeerDependencies": [
    "tslib",
    ...
  ]
}
```

---

#### Original

Just ran into this myself. This warning is coming from [`ng-packagr`](https://github.com/dherges/ng-packagr) I think (which the angular-cli relies upon to generate and package libraries). I'm not exactly sure what they mean by "whitelist," as that phrasing doesn't seem to be directly explained in ng-packagr's docs, but [this issue in the ng-packagr repo](https://github.com/dherges/ng-packagr/issues/129) has a ton of different options for how to work around the problem.

> 1. Peers (such as Angular, RxJS): in this use case, the third-party dependency is a peerDependency of your library. Users of your library need to include both your library and the third-party library in their dependencies section.
> 2. Embedding (e.g. legacy JS libraries): you have a legacy JavaScript library (e.g. an adapter to a proprietary backend) and you want to (need to) embed the legacy code in your library. In this case, the third-party dependency is a devDependency of your library and will be embedded into the bundle of your library.
> 3. Mixed mode - embedded & peer (e.g. UX guidelines, Angularized styleguide): in this use case, the third-party dependency is a peerDependency but also (partially) embedded in your library. You may want to re-use existing CSS/SCSS/LESS stylesheets from the third-party library in your library, thus "embedding" code from the third-party in your library. At the same time, the third-party dependency is a peerDependency of your library.

[The github issue](https://github.com/dherges/ng-packagr/issues/129) has more info on this.

Comment: You also need to add it to `ng-package.prod.json` for being able to build the library with `--prod`.

Comment: I needed to whitelist only the entries in `dependencies`, not in `devDependencies`

Comment: The entry needs to be added to whitelistedNonPeerDependencies array in ng-package.json and not package.json

Comment: Awesome. It's simple and woks. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 28):

Added this in `ng-package.json` and it worked for me

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "public_api.ts"
  },
  "whitelistedNonPeerDependencies": [
    "."
  ]
}
```