# Error "library" has missing dependencies - @angular/material/form-field

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a shared component library project that is a few years old (just to say it's been working fine for a while). I want to replace some of the custom components with Angular Material components. However, when I add NgMat to the library project, I get an error when attempting to use it in a separate project.

```
ERROR in The target entry-point "my library project" has missing dependencies:
- @angular/material/form-field
- @angular/material/datepicker
```

The project package.json has:

```
...
    "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.4",
...
```

And the main package.json file has:

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.4",
...
```

I've also whitelisted @angular/material in `ng-package.json` as suggested here [Dependency @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap must be explicitly whiteliste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50306714/dependency-ng-bootstrap-ng-bootstrap-must-be-explicitly-whiteliste) while having @angular/material in the project's dependencies instead of the peerDependencies.

Comment: This might not fix it but shouldn't the `@angular/cdk` be on version `10.2.4` as well?

Answer (score 0):

`@angular/material` is declared in the peerDependencies of the library package.

```
"peerDependencies": { --> Peer dependencies
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.4",
```

That means the package inside peerDependencies will not be installed automatically when you install the library.

To fix the issue,

Either you should move @angular/material to dependencies in the library package.

```
"dependencies": { --> dependencies
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.4",
```

(or) declare @angular/material in **application package.json** dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.4" --> Newly added
```

Comment: I do have @angular/material in the main package.json file. I didn't select enough lines when I copied and pasted. It's there now. I also updated the question to include additional steps.

Comment: Delete node_modules and run npm install again. If you still face, then provide a stackblitz link with the sample code.